# Android adb crashing with segmentation fault 11 on MacOS Big Sur (11.6.4). Anyone else run into this?

Tags: android, macos, crash, android-emulator, adb

Okay, so I just installed Android Studio on my new (to me) Macbook Pro. It's a mid 2014 model with i7 and 16Gigs of ram. It's fully updated to what Apple will allow, which should be plenty for Android Studio.

I've setup Emulators and coded with them using Flutter through VSCode no problem.

When I go into the terminal and run adb, all I get is Segmentation fault: 11. That's it, nothing else. It simply will not run. I plug my phone in, and of course it's not detected. I can run adb devices, which just shows none.

I've tried googling, but it seems Segmentation fault: 11 is super popular, so I can't find my way through the weeds to anything related to what I'm experiencing.

So, I've gone into Android Studio and forced it to remove the platform tools and reinstalled them through the Brew command, same thing. Is it that the latest version is incompatible with Big Sur? Should I install an older version of Android Studio? Has anyone else run into this problem? I'm hoping I'm simply overlooking something simple, but I can't for the life of me figure it out. I'm hoping to get a bit of feedback before I have to dump the whole thing and put an older version on. I have the emulator working nicely, I just want to use a physical device too.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so maybe this will help a fellow adb noob out. I recently (finally) figured out my problem, sort of. At least it's working now, so that's all I care about.

Okay, so, the first thing I ran into was that I was using a power cable, not a data cable. Rookie mistake there. So, once I had that head smacking realization, at least my phone started acting normally with the debug request.

That is, once I ran across an article the pointed out adb start-server existed. I mean, it makes sense. Maybe I'm wrong, but I would have figured that just typing adb into the terminal by itself would try and start the adb server. So, once I got that working, it finally connected with just the minimum pain that seems to go along with these types of things.

Still, I cannot understand why calling adb by itself causes a Segmentation fault, but I'll leave that up to the people who work on Android Studio to figure out, cause I'm moving on.

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you.I'll write down the steps for anyone who might need it:
1 --> cd Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/
2 --> ./adb shell (or whatever command you want to run with adb)